# Which class in Java implements the abstract class EnumSet?

Tags: java, enumset

I see that  EnumSet.of() returns an instance of an object of the type [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).
But I am not able to figure out which class actually implements this abstract class? How can you get an instance of the abstract type EnumSet, when you have not subclassed it?

Comment: Why don't you just look in the implementation of `EnumSet.of()`?

Comment: @azurefrog: You cannot instantiate an abstract class, but you can get an instance of the abstract type. For example
myAbstractClass abs= new myImplementation();
Here abs is an instance of the type myAbstractClass .

Comment: try `System.out.println(EnumSet.noneOf(RetentionPolicy.class).getClass());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is are 2 classes in java which extends `EnumSet`

```
1. RegularEnumSet
2. JumboEnumSet
```

You can create the instance using EnumSet's static methods like `EnumSet#noneOf`, `EnumSet#allOf` etc. Which actually returns the instance of `RegularEnumSet` or `JumboEnumSet` depending on the condition. `EnumSet#of` internally calls `EnumSet#noneOf`.Please refer the below code from `Java` to see how `EnumSet#noneOf` works

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> noneOf(Class<E> elementType) {
    Enum<?>[] universe = getUniverse(elementType);
    if (universe == null)
        throw new ClassCastException(elementType + " not an enum");

    if (universe.length <= 64)
        return new RegularEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
    else
        return new JumboEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not directly create instances of `EnumSet`. This is done by the static factory methods, such as:

```
enum Demo { YES, NO, FILENOTFOUND }

EnumSet<Demo> all = EnumSet.allOf(Demo.class);
EnumSet<Demo> notNo = EnumSet.of(Demo.YES, Demo.FILENOTFOUND);
EnumSet<Demo> none = EnumSet.noneOf(Demo.class);
```

The resulting sets are mutable, i.e., you can do:

```
EnumSet<Demo> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Demo.class);  // start with an empty set
...
set.add(Demo.YES);
set.remove(Demo.NO);
...
set.clear();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> A specialized Set implementation for use with enum types. All of the elements in an enum set must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the set is created.

You can't create a instance if `EnumSet`! However also you don't need to extend it, for it's purpose there is a factory method to create a Set from specified elements:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> of(E first, E... rest)
```

It creates an object for you. Often EnumSets are used for combining effects, whether it's text styles e.g. BOLD and UNDERLINE or with colors...

```
enum Color { GREEN, RED, BLUE };
EnumSet <Color> yellow = EnumSet.of(Color.RED, Color.GREEN);
```

You found additional information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)...

Answer (score 0):

To find this information, you could look at all the code, or print out the `getClass()` of the object returned as a sample but a simpler way is to use your IDE.

Navigate to `EnumSet` and click the icon showing the implementations

[image: implementations of EnumSet]

This shows you a list of all the available sub-classes of EnumSet available.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already answered what are the concrete subclasses of `EnumSet` that actually implement the abstract class `EnumSet`.   I will attempt to clarify how we can get an instance of the abstract type `EnumSet`, when we have not subclassed it.

Observe that `EnumSet` does not have a constructor, so it is not intended to be used like a normal class:

`EnumSet set = new EnumSet(...); // not like this`

Rather, to create an `EnumSet`, we use one of its static initializers (such as `of`).   These initializers will internally create an object of type either `JumboEnumSet` (if the number of enum constants is large) or `RegularEnumSet` (otherwise) and return the reference of that object.

Since `JumboEnumSet` and `RegularEnumSet` are both subclasses of `EnumSet`, they can be assigned to a variable of type `EnumSet` (this is known as [widening reference conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)).

The beauty of this is that when we use the variable of type `EnumSet`, we do not have to know which concrete implementation we are using.   In fact, both `JumboEnumSet` and `RegularEnumSet` are both private class in the package `java.util` so we can't even create it directly.

You can explore more how `EnumSet` is implemented internally through its source (see, for instance [here for the Java 9's version](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/EnumSet.java)).

Another example of commonly use type in Java that is not actually a concrete class is `Stream`.  `Stream` is actually an interface.